# Имитация клика или "фокусировка" на элемент. jquery

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Сделал всплывающий div с прокруткой. Т.е как блок всплыл то body style="overflow:hidden".
Так вот если крутить колесиком в этом блоке то все нормально..НО однажды обратил внимание как друг читает новости вконтакте)) нажимая пробел. 
Так вот если у меня нажать пробел то все равно прокручивается сам body. хотя прокрутки невидно. Но если кликнуть внутри всплывшего дива, то по нажатию пробела прокручивается он.
Подскажите может кто знает как сделать что бы при загрузке произошел "аля клик" или что то в этом духе. попробовал focus().. click() не получилось) больше вообще нет  идей(

Answer (score 1):

Для div c id='foo' делаем так:

```
$(function(){
  $('#foo').focus();
});
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Persio/65jep/)